# What is this red substance that has accumulated at the bottom of a plastic bottle full of petrol (see picture)?

Tags: plastics, fuel

About two weeks ago I put some ordinary unleaded petrol into a plastic water bottle, as a temporary measure (long story, don't ask!). It has now formed a reddish liquid at the bottom of the bottle.

The bottle was emptied prior to adding the petrol, but probably still contained a small amount of water when the fuel was poured in. The bottle was stored in ordinary room temperature.

I presume that the fuel has corroded/reacted with the plastic and left this substance, but I have looked to Stack Exchange in the hope of a more scientific answer...

So, what is the red substance and cause of it?

[image: The red substance]

*Please note that the brownish 'slug-shape' is merely an artifact of the light refraction...*

Comment: I assume that the petrol you put in was poured out the same day and what little remained is what turned brown. Is that correct?

Comment: No, the bottle was 'clean', then filled to the brim with fuel, sealed, and the red/brown is a liquid that settled on the bottom whilst the bottle is still sealed and full of fuel. The picture above has a yellowish tint: it is still sealed and full of fuel, it is not empty in the picture. Very strange....!

Comment: If there is still petrol in the bottle, then the lower layer must be mostly water. Is the fuel an ethanol blend?

Comment: It's super unleaded (so 95 octane) from a UK petrol station.... Sorry, I'm no Chemist so don't know!

Comment: Any idea what plastic it is?

Comment: It might say on the bottom in symbols, or on the neck.

Comment: 95 unleaded for sure contains good amount of oxygenates and/or alkenes. My bet, traces of water leaded to separation of oxygenates (alcohols) into separate phase and then formed polar phase extracted some colored components from the mixture. However, it is impossible to give exact details without complicated chemical analysis or full listing of fuel composition

Comment: Could be a chemical reaction between the fuel and the bottle. Some plastics e.g. LDPE are not very resistant to just the sort of hydrocarbons of which petrol is composed.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe could be some iron oxide or hydroxide from previous storage or ( if you have a iron tap) from it ore maybe directly from the plastic.

Some fuel has red dye in it but I don't think this is the case, because I don't see how it can precipitate.

Maybe it could be a residue of [petroleum resin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petroleum_resin).

Comment: It came from the pump, into a jerry can then into the plastic bottle...the fuel in the jerry can is clean and doesn't have this red substance which makes me think it must be reacting with the plastic.

Comment: I wouldn't think it would be iron (III) oxide or iron hydroxide in that kind of quantity. I think it could be petroleum resin though.

Comment: Do you have any sources to support 'petroleum resin' being present in petrol (gasoline)? It seems unlikely to me.

Comment: @nekomatic no, is more an hypothesis...